# uninitialized constant error for a lot of gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

after going through a lot of forums I conclude that I'm asking this question for a lot of guys who don't know the answer to this question, a lot of times when we do require a certain gem in the Gemfile and do bundle install, the gems get installed but when we do something like ::.something in a controller, and run it on the local server, lot of times it just throws out this uninitialized constant ::
Sometimes this error seems to go away by itself, other times it just stays, trying to find out where exactly this problem could be, its a routing or config error I feel. Where do you think this error could be? where should I be looking?
To make things more specfic, right now I'm using the xmpp4r gem.
I have this line "gem 'xmpp4r'" in my gemfile, I ran bundle install.
Then in the controller I put these two lines

> > client = Jabber::Client.new(jid)
> >     client.auth('1234')
> >     message = Jabber::Message::new(to_jid, body).set_type(:normal).set_id('1')
> >     my_muc = Jabber::MUC::SimpleMUCClient.new(client)

The weird part is it gives no error for the client or message but it says it can't find the MUC module, then I went through the rvm and I tried to find the physical location of them xmpp4r gem, there I found the MUC.rb file and in the comments it says use like this

> > my_muc = Jabber::MUC::SimpleMUCClient.new(my_client)

the error the server gave was

> > uninitialized constant Jabber::MUC

So guys here you go, if you could solve this issue, we'll all be very thankful.

Alright, 10 minutes it took to resolve this issue on stackoverflow, cheers to the creators and the community that runs it, specifically gmile.

So if you are getting an error like this, I guess its cause the virtual machine doesn't recursively go through all the folders in the gem and add all the .rb files, we have to specifically require the file in our controller.
Just go to the

> > .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/

mess around and see if the module you are trying to access is there, then see if it is inside subfolders in the gem and then add those folders like

> > require 'gemname/subfolder'

CHEERS

Answer (score 0):

Trying putting this on top of your file:

```
require 'xmpp4r'
require 'xmpp4r/muc'
```